# Selenium Send keys intermittently skips over text fields

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am writing automation tests that send keys to every text box on a form (about 5 fields) and then a submit button becomes enabled and clicked. I find that the test frequently fails as only the last field is populated and the button never becomes enabled.

It seems like the method to send keys may be executing too fast for the page to be populated. So far I have attempted to click on each field before sending keys (as well as waiting for the elements to exist) and this doesn't seem to help.

I have also tried to verify the page is fully loaded by waiting for every element and button to exist on the page before proceeding.

The browser I am testing against is chrome. (Version 79.0.3945.130)
The selenium web-driver is 3.11.2
The chrome driver is up to date with chrome

```
private IWebElement FirstNameInput => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("first-name-input"));
// The remaining input fields

public void VerifyPageIsFullyLoaded()
{
    // Wait until all elements exist
}

public void EnterFormDetails(FormDetail formDetail) 
{
    WebDriver.WaitUntilElementExists(FirstNameInput);
    FirstNameInput.Click();
    FirstNameInput.SendKeys(formDetail.FirstName);

    WebDriver.WaitUntilElementExists(LastNameInput);
    LastNameInput.Click();
    LastNameInput.SendKeys(formDetail.LastName);

    WebDriver.WaitUntilElementExists(DateOfBirthInput);
    DateOfBirthInput.Click();
    DateOfBirthInput.SendKeys(formDetail.DateOfBirth);

    WebDriver.WaitUntilElementIsClickable(SubmitButton);
    SubmitButton.Click();
}
```

Update:
Just tried the latest stable release of selenium web driver (3.141.0) and found that it is still not as reliable.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Which version of the browser and web driver are you using? Which browser are you using? Can you post the full code in the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor)webdriver;

javascript.executeScript("document.getElementById('FirstNameInput').value='test123'");
javascript.executeScript("document.getElementById('LastNameInput').value='test123'");
javascript.executeScript("document.getElementById('DateOfBirthInput').value='test123'");

SubmitButton.Click();
```

and if the submit button is in form tag then you can use `submit()` method.